# Не могу в R пакете установить функцию maBina

Tags: r

```
install.packages("maBina")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Найс/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
```

Выводит вот такую ошибку:

> Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘maBina’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)

Comment: Может посмотреть в документации к пакету какую версию R он требует и установить нужную?

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так:

```
install.packages("erer")
```

предполагаю, что `maBina` одна из функций из пакета `erer`
а по ссылке ниже список всех функций
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/erer/versions/2.5

Answer (score 0):

`maBina` является функцией пакета `erer`. Соответственно, нужно устанавливать его